# possessive apostrophe and THE for academic phrases

Tags: possessives, apostrophe, possessive-pronouns, possessive-adjectives, academic-writing

I am applying for PhD. In university's site I have seen several possessive phrases which have completely confused me. Which of these are correct?

1- UCI EECS Department / UCI Department of EECS / UCI's EECS's Department / UCI's EECS Department / UCI EECS's Department) (in this [link](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=uci%20eecs%20faculty&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8), as you see, they have used UCI EECS Department and [here](https://grad.uci.edu/academics/degree-programs/academic-masters/ElectricalEngineeringMS.php), they have written "The UCI Department of Electrical Engineering and Computer Science". Should I use always THE before UCI which is abbreviation? For example, they have written somewhere the UCI department and somewhere else they have written "UCI engineering" (without THE)). Which one is correct?

2. (The?) UCI EECS’s graduate program / UCI's EECS’s graduate program / UCI EECS graduate program? This part is somewhat like above. Should I igonre s in s in EECS's write it EECS'? it ends up with S!
3. EECS faculty/EECS's faculty/EECS' faculty? Also in [this page](https://grad.uci.edu/academics/degree-programs/academic-masters/ElectricalEngineeringMS.php) they have not used THE for EECS despite it is sth specific (EECS, home to more than 50 percent of ...). It seems wrong!
4. faculty members/members of faculty/faculty's members? I have not seen two latter, but I don't know that how first one describes possession relationship between two words??

Sorry for lengthy question. Thanks for reading my question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

> *The UCI Department of Electrical Engineering and Computer Science..."*

... is a half sentence.

The full one is -

> *The UCI Department of Electrical Engineering and Computer Science has two key goals:*

There, the general rule of *the* is applied. If you are specific about something, use the *definite* article. Here, they are peculiar about the department as they have named it.

On the other hand, if you are writing a title or just the name of the department, you may drop *the.* However, mind it that the word *department* is a bit complex as far as the usage of an article is concerned. **A [good read is here.](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/wrtps/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_n&page=96lAjS4ioNx4.html)**

For *"...home to..."* portion, they have used an abbreviation of the said department which itself serves as a *proper noun* omitting the article.

Next, as far as *apostrophe* is concerned, it is [a noun adjunct.](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/attributive--noun) It is okay as *EECS faculty* again as EECS served as *a noun or one word.*

Comment: Thanks @Maulik V♦ for the answer. what about case 2? Is UCI EECS graduate program correct?

Comment: I would prefer - *The UCI EECS' graduate program.*

Comment: Thanks again @Maulik V♦ for the comment. Is it a rule or just a preference, sth related to style?

Comment: It's guidelines.